# LibreOffice: How to create shortcut key to Insert->Object->Formula

Tags: shortcut-keys, libreoffice

I'm trying to add a shortcut-key to this options.
I go to Tools->Customize-> Keyboard (Tab), and I see this:

[image]

I don't see the option Object->Formula. The 'Formula' in Function list is not what I'm looking for. Do you know how to get a shortcut-key for this option?

Answer (score 0):

The second Formula in your photo may be what you want, it work the same function as the `Insert->Object->Formula`